# Как позиционировать изображение под разрешение и размер экрана

Tags: javascript

Как раскусить эту фишку на этом сайте http://www.elenavasichkina.com/album/9/ а конкретно независимо от расширения будь то 1280x768 или 1920x1080 картинки здесь при любом расширении отображаются на всю высоту экрана!!!
Я заметил что при загрузке картинки сперва отображается анимашка, но это не Flash, или скрипт какой то подключен?
У меня же получается полоса в низу http://emelinna.ru/
Я уже перелопатил этот сайт Firebug - ом, но ни как не могу понять как это работает.
Я так понимаю здесь скрипт подстраивает, масштабирует изображение под расширение того монитора где этот сайт запускается, то есть ява.

Comment: я так и не понял что там особенного?
Размер картинок == размеру страницы, что тут тяжелого?

Comment: Оно http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size "Масштабирует фоновое изображение согласно заданным размерам"?

Answer (score 1):

elenavasichkina.com — калека. Там контейнер `div.slider`, в котором лежит таблица (1 строка), в каждой ячейке которой лежит `<img>`. А в фоне каждой ячейки — картинка-preloader. Получается, когда фотка прогрузилась, она закрывает собой эту анимацию. А у `<body>` прописано свойство `overflow-y:hidden`.

Я не стал разузнавать, с моим хромом что-то не так, или так и запланировано, но у меня горизонтальная прокрутка есть. Это мне на показалось здоровским. А как давно вы хватали ползунок скроллбара вместо использования колесика мыши? Я понимаю, что на планшете это удобно (не факт, что браузер нормально отработает `overflow-y:hidden` в этом случае). Потому и калека. А еще там зачем-то отступ сверху.

А вот тебе осталось только картинки вытащить из фона и вставить их традиционным способом, а у их контейнера и их родителей указать свойство `height:100%` (вплоть до `<body>`) или просто позиционировать весь блок с контейнером как-то так:

```
position: absolute;  /* в этом случае — относительно body */
z-index: -1;
left:0px;
right:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
```

`<body>` тогда тоже должен по высоте и ширине занимать всю рабочую область.

Но на emelinna.ru я заблудился в дереве, так что, возможно, что-то нужно будет поменять (там на мой взгляд очень много лишних элементов, создающих избыточную вложенность).